# How to solve the CameraX app's being unresponsive?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, androidx, android-camerax

The emulator becomes almost unresponsive (I am not able to pan the camera) and consumes too much computational power (CPU & GPU) when my sample `CameraX` app, which is based on that [GitHub repository](https://github.com/thunderedge/CameraX), is being run. Could you please guide me through for reason of this situation?

**Update (11.07.2019):** With the latest updates to the `CameraX` libraries (`1.0.0-alpha03`), nothing is being displayed on the screen except than the image button.

**Here is the code of my activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextureView textureView;
    private ImageButton captureButton;

    private int REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initComponents();
        checkPermissions();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        textureView = findViewById(R.id.viewFinder);
        captureButton = findViewById(R.id.captureButton);
    }

    private void checkPermissions() {
        final String permission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
        boolean isPermissionGranted = PermissionUtil.checkForPermission(this, permission);
        if (!isPermissionGranted) {
            boolean rationale = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    MainActivity.this, permission);
            if (rationale) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Camera Permission");
                builder.setMessage("In order to take the photo of your vein, you need to grant camera permission.");
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_info_accent);

                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            } else
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
        } else
            startCamera();
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startCamera();
            }
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    private void startCamera() {
        //make sure there isn't another camera instance running before starting
        CameraX.unbindAll();

        /* start preview */
        int aspRatioW = textureView.getWidth(); //get width of screen
        int aspRatioH = textureView.getHeight(); //get height
        Rational asp = new Rational(aspRatioW, aspRatioH); //aspect ratio
        Size screen = new Size(aspRatioW, aspRatioH); //size of the screen

        //config obj for preview/viewfinder thingy.
        PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(asp).setTargetResolution(screen).build();
        Preview preview = new Preview(pConfig); //lets build it

        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
                new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener() {
                    //to update the surface texture we  have to destroy it first then re-add it
                    @Override
                    public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput output) {
                        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) textureView.getParent();
                        parent.removeView(textureView);
                        parent.addView(textureView, 0);

                        textureView.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
                        updateTransform();
                    }
                });


        /* image capture */

        //config obj, selected capture mode
        ImageCaptureConfig imgCConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
                .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).build();
        final ImageCapture imgCap = new ImageCapture(imgCConfig);


        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(MainActivity.this);
                String path = contextWrapper.getFilesDir().getPath();
                File file = new File(path + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                imgCap.takePicture(file, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                        String msg = "Photo capture succeeded: " + file.getAbsolutePath();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.UseCaseError useCaseError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                        String msg = "Photo capture failed: " + message;
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (cause != null) {
                            cause.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        /* image analyser */

        ImageAnalysisConfig imgAConfig = new ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder().setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE).build();
        ImageAnalysis analysis = new ImageAnalysis(imgAConfig);

        analysis.setAnalyzer(
                new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
                    @Override
                    public void analyze(ImageProxy image, int rotationDegrees) {
                        //y'all can add code to analyse stuff here idek go wild.
                    }
                });

        //bind to lifecycle:
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) this, analysis, imgCap, preview);
    }

    private void updateTransform() {
        //compensates the changes in orientation for the viewfinder, bc the rest of the layout stays in portrait mode.
        //methinks :thonk:
        Matrix mx = new Matrix();
        float w = textureView.getMeasuredWidth();
        float h = textureView.getMeasuredHeight();

        float cX = w / 2f; //calc centre of the viewfinder
        float cY = h / 2f;

        int rotationDgr;
        int rotation = (int) textureView.getRotation(); //cast to int bc switches don't like floats

        switch (rotation) { //correct output to account for display rotation
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                rotationDgr = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                rotationDgr = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                rotationDgr = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                rotationDgr = 270;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

        mx.postRotate((float) rotationDgr, cX, cY);
        textureView.setTransform(mx); //apply transformations to textureview
    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CameraActivity">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/textureView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnCapture"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Activity]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem too, even the sample app from CameraX had the same issue on my emulator. One line of code fixed this for me.
Change this:

```
ImageAnalysisConfig imgAConfig = new ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder()
    .setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE).build();
```

To this:

```
ImageAnalysisConfig imgAConfig = new ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder()
    .setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE)
    .setTargetResolution(Size(1280, 720)).build();
```

By setting a target resolution the problem was fixed in my case. Hope it might help you or others.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same thing but it does work on a regular phone. The `ImageAnalysis` class seems to be the issue. When I leave the `analysis` use case off the `CameraX.bindToLifecycle` call I am able to use the emulator. I hope this helps. You can definitely tell CameraX is in alpha.